# Описание знака «Возрождение»

Tags: предложение, дефект, статус-завершено

Получила сегодня знак «Возрождение» (["Склонение имён среднего рода"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463662/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)).
Обратила внимание на такую запись:

> Вы заработали знак «Возрождение» (Ответить более чем через 30 дней после того, как вопрос был задан и получить за первый ответ минимум 2 балла.) за «Склонение имён среднего рода».

Мне кажется, что здесь допущены ошибки.

1. В общем описании знака запятыми надо выделить "после того как вопрос был задан" (союз "после того как" входит в придаточное предложение целиком):
   *Ответить более чем через 30 дней, после того как вопрос был задан, и получить за первый ответ минимум 2 балла.*
2. Вставка является частью предложения, поэтому после открывающей скобки текст пишется со строчной буквы и перед закрывающей скобкой точка не ставится:
   *Вы заработали знак «Возрождение» (ответить более чем через 30 дней, после того как вопрос был задан, и получить за первый ответ минимум 2 балла) за «Склонение имён среднего рода».*

Можно, конечно, и в скобках использовать кавычки (без точки), но тогда их в предложении будет три комплекта.
Можно в скобках использовать курсив (без точки).

Comment: По-моему, запятая может быть и как там, и перед союзом, но закрывающая, конечно, нужна. Не понял, зачем кавычки или курсив. Точка не нужна, тут вы правы на 100%. ;)

Comment: Просто кавычки или курсив позволяют написать предложение в скобках с заглавной буквы — как цитату. А предложение _Ответить более чем через 30 дней и получить за первый ответ минимум 2 балла_ мне больше нравится, чем то, которое мы получаем при разделении союза — _Ответить более чем через 30 дней после того и получить за первый ответ минимум 2 балла_.

Comment: Да, об этом я думал, но нашёл на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_593#:~:text=%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%95%20%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%9E(%2C)%20%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A%2C,%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%C2%AB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%C2%BB) и подобный пример.

Comment: Простите, что долго отвечал! Советы по улучшению локализации очень ценны, буду благодарен за другие предложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое спасибо! Исправил перевод на

> ответить более чем через 30 дней после того, как вопрос был задан, и получить за первый ответ минимум 2 балла

Насчет переноса места запятой не уверен, что должно быть, как вы написали. Но если дадите ссылку на правило, то исправлю и это!